# How to configure SSL on ActiveMQ Artemis Cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a cluster where the connectors and acceptors are configured like this:

Server1:

```xml
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server1:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
        
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

Server 2:

```xml
     <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server2:61616</connector>
     </connectors>
        
     <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE</acceptor>
     </acceptors>
```

Now I create for each server a (Self-Signed) server-certificate. Do I need to set both `keystorePath` and `truststorePath` for both `connector` and `acceptor`? Or do I only need a `keystorePath` for the `acceptor` and `truststorePath` for the `connector`?

I saw several examples, but none that works well (got handshake errors). What is a correct setup?

I tried this setup:

Server1:

```xml
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server1:61616?enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2;sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=client-ca-truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=securepass</connector>
      </connectors>
        
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE;sslEnabled=true;needClientAuth=true;keyStorePath=server1-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

Server 2:

```xml
     <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server2:61616?enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2;sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=client-ca-truststore.jks;trustStorePassword=securepass</connector>
     </connectors>
        
     <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE;sslEnabled=true;needClientAuth=true;keyStorePath=server2-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=securepass</acceptor>
     </acceptors>
```

On server1 I get this error:

```
WARN 57399 --- [Thread-7 (activemq-netty-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server : AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /10.96.1.102:35944: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Empty client certificate chain.
```

And on server 2

```
ERROR 60482 --- [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@7b3af62e)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client : AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ActiveMQChannelHandler has been found while connecting to server1/10.96.1.6:61616 from Channel with id = b4c31575
WARN 60482 --- [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@7b3af62e)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server : AMQ222186: unable to authorise cluster control: AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response
```

When I start one of the brokers, it  start normally. The errors occur when the other node is online. Server1 and server2 always have the same errors despite starting order.

Certificates were created with keytool (seems fine in keystore explorer).

Is the setup incorrect, or is there something wrong with the certificates?

The previous setup of Artemis at the organization had mutual SSL, but there's no benefit in two-way authentication for my use case. As my setup wasn't working I added it again, but I thought it only enforced clients to authenticate through user/password.

Comment: I also checked "ssl-enabled-dual-authentication" example, but this didn't work either.

Comment: The basic need is a secure and encrypted communication (between broker node in the cluster and brokers and clients). Clients connect through a failover connection with username/password and sslenabled (tls 1.2 or higher).

Comment: The previous setup of Artemis at the organization had mutual SSL, but as you said there's no benefit in two-way authentication for my use case.  As my setup wasn't working I added it again, but I thought it only enforced clients to authenticate through user/password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237471/discussion-between-justin-bertram-and-user2209562).

Comment: After removing "needClientAuth=true", so that mutual-ssl isn't required, the broker started normal. You may update your answer with that. I'm still struggling with the Qpid Client and SSL, but that's another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using self-signed certificates then you need to specify `keyStorePath` and `keyStorePassword` on the `acceptor` and `trustStorePath` and `trustStorePassword` on the `connector`. Of course both will need `sslEnabled=true`.

The broker ships with an example that uses self-signed certificates in the `examples/features/standard/ssl-enabled` directory. This essentially demonstrates what is necessary for this use-case although in a slightly different way than what you're doing. Just think of the client in the example as the `connector` in the clustered use-case because that is exactly what it is. There are even commands in the documentation for how to generate all the SSL resources.

In the configuration you attempted you specified `needClientAuth=true` on your `acceptor` which is almost certainly causing problems. This setting is for enabling "mutual" (i.e. 2-way) SSL, but your question says nothing about this. I don't believe you need this. I recommend you remove it.

Comment: It check the ssl-enabled example, but this doesn't contain a connector and doesn't have multiple servers. I enhanced my question with one of the things I tried.

Comment: I understand the example doesn't have a `connector`. That's why I said, "Just think of the client in the example as the connector in the clustered use-case because that is exactly what it is." If  you look at the client's URL in the example it uses `sslEnabled=true`, `trustStorePath`, & `trustStorePassword` as I described.

Comment: Did you actually try setting `keyStorePath` and `keyStorePassword` on the `acceptor` and `trustStorePath` and `trustStorePassword` on the `connector` and `sslEnabled=true` on both as my answer describes? If so, what was the result? If not, why not?

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. I thought I had done this in my example? Can you please provide a correct setup so that I can compare with? I tried many setups, but none was working.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so could you make it as correct to help others who have this same question in the future? If not, please elaborate as to what problem remains. Thanks!

Comment: The issue was with "needClientAuth=true". I thought it meant that the clients of the broker needs authentication (like user/password). The parameter, as explained, should only to be used when using mutual SSL/TLS. In my case it was enough to set keystore with the server certificate on the acceptor and truststore with client certificates on the connector. The last part didn't work at first, because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454355/org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-client-amq214013-failed-to-decode-packet