# org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client : AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a cluster of two ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0 brokers. The "server2" broker has the following in its `broker.xml`:

```xml
<connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server1:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/.assimbly/security/truststore-01.jks;truststorePassword=secret</connector>
</connectors>
        
<acceptors>
     <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/.assimbly/security/keystore-01.jks;keyStorePassword=secret</acceptor>
         
     <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?protocols=CORE,AMQP;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/.assimbly/security/keystore-01.jks;keyStorePassword=secret</acceptor>
</acceptors>

    <cluster-connections>
       <cluster-connection name="test-cluster">
          <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
          <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
          <use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>
          <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
          <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="test-discovery-group"/>
       </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
```

The broker starts normally without SSL enabled. However, when SSL is enabled in `broker.xml` the broker starts (on server2) with the following error:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client : AMQ212037: Connection failure to server1/10.96.1.6:61616 has been detected: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client : AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38
```

Currently, there are no messages on the broker (fresh start). I can't pinpoint where the "length=1970500723" is coming from.

What could be the issue?

Stack trace:

```
2021-10-05 12:37:50,496 WARN  [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@1f8d7d07)] client: AMQ212037: Connection failure to lnx00057.svb.org/10.96.1.6:61616 has been detected: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2021-10-05 12:37:50,508 ERROR [Thread-10 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] client: AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString.readSimpleString(SimpleString.java:185)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString.readSimpleString(SimpleString.java:173)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readStringInternal(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readNullableString(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:88)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.wireformat.ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3.decodeRest(ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.wireformat.ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V4.decodeRest(ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V4.java:56)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketImpl.decode(PacketImpl.java:371)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.slowPathDecode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:277)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.decode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:149)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:388)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1263)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1374)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1237)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
2021-10-05 12:37:50,508 ERROR [Thread-10 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)] client: AMQ214031: Failed to decode buffer, disconnect immediately.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:401)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1263)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1374)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1237)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString.readSimpleString(SimpleString.java:185)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString.readSimpleString(SimpleString.java:173)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readStringInternal(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readNullableString(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:88)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.wireformat.ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3.decodeRest(ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V3.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.wireformat.ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V4.decodeRest(ClusterTopologyChangeMessage_V4.java:56)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketImpl.decode(PacketImpl.java:371)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.slowPathDecode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:277)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ServerPacketDecoder.decode(ServerPacketDecoder.java:149)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:388)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
2021-10-05 12:37:50,508 WARN  [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@1f8d7d07)] client: AMQ212037: Connection failure to lnx00057.svb.org/10.96.1.6:61616 has been detected: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38 [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2021-10-05 12:37:50,530 WARN  [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@1f8d7d07)] client: AMQ212025: did not connect the cluster connection to other nodes
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException: AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.cluster.DiscoveryGroup@2f9129bc
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:743)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:549)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:528)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl$4.run(ServerLocatorImpl.java:486)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)
2021-10-05 12:37:50,531 WARN  [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@1f8d7d07)] server: AMQ224091: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@5ba37c27 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.test-cluster.918859b6-25f5-11ec-8bff-001dd8c12fe4, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.test-cluster.918859b6-25f5-11ec-8bff-001dd8c12fe4, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=02], temp=false]@55648923 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl (identity=(Cluster-connection-bridge::ClusterConnectionBridge@5ba37c27 [name=$.artemis.internal.sf.test-cluster.918859b6-25f5-11ec-8bff-001dd8c12fe4, queue=QueueImpl[name=$.artemis.internal.sf.test-cluster.918859b6-25f5-11ec-8bff-001dd8c12fe4, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=02], temp=false]@55648923 targetConnector=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&sslEnabled=true&host=lnx00057-svb-org&trustStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/-assimbly/security/truststore-01-jks], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]]::ClusterConnectionImpl@1709963701[nodeUUID=98f793bf-25f5-11ec-9e30-001dd8c12fe5, connector=TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?trustStorePassword=****&port=61616&sslEnabled=true&host=lnx00058-svb-org&trustStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/-assimbly/security/truststore-01-jks, address=, server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=02])) [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=netty-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?port=61616&sslEnabled=true&host=lnx00057-svb-org&trustStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/-assimbly/security/truststore-01-jks], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null]] is unable to connect to destination. Retrying
```

The last log line indicates that the `discoveryGroupConfiguration=null`. I'm not sure if this is directly related or a separated issue. Here is the configuration of these groups:

```xml
    <broadcast-groups>
       <broadcast-group name="test-broadcast-group">
        <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
       </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="test-discovery-group">
            <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>
```

I tried changing the `group-address` of my `discovery-group` and `broadcast-group` to use `231.6.6.6` instead of `231.7.7.7` on both nodes, but the failure still occurred.

Comment: I am using Artemis 2.18.0. I wanted to paste the full broker.xml, but then I can't save the question. The message is then: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.".

Comment: Yes, at the moment there are only two brokers in the cluster. One on server1 and one on server2. Using UDP broadcasting/discovery.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to attach it (as code). Try to attach it as text.

Comment: At the last line of the attached log. Not sure if this is directly related or a separated issue.

Comment: I changed it on both nodes, but same result. The error only goes away when not using ssl anymore.

Comment: I'm using an (embedded) broker. I don't see a log on connection. It only logs when the other node gets disconnected, for example: "The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]"

Comment: Yes, the messages are blocked by default. I changed it so org.apache* is shown. Now I see the following: "o.a.a.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl : AMQ841000: created connection: RemotingConnectionImpl [ID=1ab88555, clientID=null, nodeID=918859b6-25f5-11ec-8bff-001dd8c12fe4, transportConnection=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyServerConnection@44dbfc31[ID=1ab88555, local= /10.96.1.6:61616, remote=/10.96.1.102:51306]]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237851/discussion-between-user2209562-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: When making a cluster with static discovery, I get the INFO message in the log:

org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server : AMQ221027: Bridge ClusterConnectionBridge@788bb9cc

Then I enable SSL. When turning on the first broker node I am able to connect with a AMQP/Qpid client over SSL (no errors). I can
also send messages. When turning on the second broker node the error returns. This also happens when using a stripped down configuration (for example the features/clustered-static-discovery)

Comment: When using federation, instead of clustering, the error does not appear.  Messages flow between broker nodes (also with SSL enabled).

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error you should replace truststorePassword with trust**S**torePassword because the check for allowed connector parameters is case sensitive.

This issue is caused by the not [allowed connector parameters](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/remoting/impl/netty/TransportConstants.java#L444) because they are handled as extra parameters and there is an error on [encoding](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/TransportConfiguration.java#L340) and [decoding](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.19.0/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/TransportConfiguration.java#L361) TransportConfiguration ExtraParams, see [ARTEMIS-3363](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3363) for further details.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found this out eventually. The error was a bit cryptic. Hope that ARTEMIS-3363 get solved and that it will give a message like "Invalid parameter X on connector with name Y. One of Z is expected"

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because on connecting to the other node, the url in the connector is too long for the simpleString:

```xml
<connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server1:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/data/assimbly/broker/.assimbly/security/truststore-01.jks;truststorePassword=secret</connector>
</connectors>
```

The error message gives some information:

```
Error reading in simpleString, length=1970500723 is greater than readableBytes=38
```

The length=1970500723 is not the length of characters or bytes. It's part of the URL. When decoding it:

```
  Decimal to Hexadecimal (1970500723 --> 75737473)
  Hexadecimal to ASCII (75737473 --> usts)
```

The 'usts' relates to 'trustStorePath' in the connector. This URL parameter is a valid way for [configuring the transport](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html). On testing the error didn't occur when using the standalone Artemis distribution, but it did occur when using an [embedded broker](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/embedding-activemq.html).

The solution was to change the URL to:

```xml
<connectors>
       <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://server1:61616?sslEnabled=true</connector>
</connectors>
```

And then start the java application with the following system properties:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/truststore.jks  -Dorg.apache.activemq.ssl.trustStore=secret -jar MyApp.jar
```